# Best solution for different requests and using Loader?

Tags: android, android-loader

I using `Loader's` in my app. I'm want make differnent requests (get data from network) and all this must correctly worked when I rotate screen.

Can I use own `Loader` for each requests?

p.s. I didnt find this in docs.

Comment: For starters: link to [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html)

Comment: @0X0nosugar I read it) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how often your app does requests. Does the order of results matter?

Of course, you can use multiple Loaders. To differentiate Loaders (if want to) you have to define many ids, then use switch statements in onCreateLoader, onLoadFinished, onLoaderReset.

I guess, Loaders are executed in the same thread (as AsyncTasks), so one worker can block others...

Did you consider to use Service?